# How to adjust the output of kubectl get pods in kubernetes to watch pods status

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster perfectly working fine. I use below command to get the status of all the pods running in my namespace `dataspace`

```
kubectl get pods -n dataspace -o wide | sort -k7
```

Above command gives me the output with below columns.

```
NAME               READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE       IP            NODE
deployment-qw3ed   3/3       Running             3          3d        10.38.0.10    MACHINE01
```

Can we adjust above command so that the output looks like below. `NODE` column should  come after the `STATUS`:

```
NAME               READY     STATUS     NODE         RESTARTS   AGE       IP            
deployment-qw3ed   3/3       Running    MACHINE01    3          3d        10.38.0.10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-arrange the output with `awk` which loses the pretty column separation but you can then make it pretty again with `column`:

`kubectl get pods -n dataspace  -o wide | sort -k7 | awk '{ print $1, $2, $3, $7, $4, $5, $6}' | column -t`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with piping through `sort` is the heading ends up at the bottom.

```
kubectl get pods -A -o wide --sort-by="{.spec.nodeName}" | awk '{ print $2, $3, $4, $8, $5, $6, $7}' | column -t
```

```
NAME                                        READY  STATUS   NODE           RESTARTS  AGE    IP
coredns-5d78c9869d-rpd6g                    1/1    Running  master-node    0         158m   10.85.0.2
coredns-5d78c9869d-mk479                    1/1    Running  master-node    0         158m   10.85.0.4
kube-proxy-c65mn                            1/1    Running  master-node    0         158m   192.168.1.20
calico-kube-controllers-786b679988-j75rg    1/1    Running  master-node    0         158m   10.85.0.3
```